# A perfect shuffle on $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations, infinite-combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

**Motivation.** This weekend I was playing the pair-matching game *Memory* (also called [*Concentration*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_(card_game)) in other parts of the world) against my youngest son, and wondered about what constitutes a "good shuffle" of the cards. Remember that every card appears exactly twice in the deck of cards. The definition I came up with is: A shuffle is *good* if the following holds: When we stack the cards, corresponding pairs have different distances. For example, consider a "baby concentration game" with 2 pairs only: then the order $A - B - B - A$ would be "good" in this working definition, since pair $A$ has distance $3$, and pair $B$ has distance $1$.

While I kept losing round after round, the following question materialized.

**Formal & infinite version.** Let $\mathbb{N} = \{0, 1, 2, 3,\ldots\}$ be the set of non-negative integers. We regard the $2$-sets $\{2k, 2k+1\}$ as a "pair" in the sense of the concentration game.

Is there a bijection $\varphi:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ with the following property?

> For all $n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$ there is a unique $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\varphi(2k+1) - \varphi(2k) = n$.

Comment: $0,1,2,4,3,6,5,9,7,12,8,14,10,17,11,19,13,22\dotsc$. If you take the naturals to begin with one instead of zero, the greedy algorithm gives https://oeis.org/A072061 $1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 7, 6, 10, 8, 13, 9, 15, 11, 18, 12, 20, 14, 23, 16, 26, 17, 28, 19, 31, 21, 34, 22, 36, 24, 39, 25, 41, 27, 44, 29, 47, 30, 49, 32, 52, 33, 54, 35, 57, 37, 60, 38, 62, 40, 65, 42, 68, 43, 70, 45, 73, 46, 75, 48, 78, 50, 81, 51, 83, 53, 86, 55, 89, 56, 91, 58,\dotsc$.

Comment: Such permutation is easily constructed turn-by-turn. On $k$th turn you ensure that the pair $(2k,3k+1)$ is already in the domain, and the number $k$ is among the differences (by using some unused pair).

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453577/a-perfect-shuffle-on-mathbbn#comment1173436_453577), does that obviously ensure uniqueness? \\ I could have sworn that you (@‍DominicvanderZypen) had a previous question also coming from playing Memory/Concentration with your son, but I can no longer find it.  Am I imagining it?

Comment: You are right, @LSpice, you are maybe referring to this question? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382642/memory-game-inspired-problem (then I was losing against the other son).

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453577/a-perfect-shuffle-on-mathbbn#comment1173494_453577), yes, that's probably it.

Comment: @LSpice preserve only the property that all differences are different, that's easy.

Comment: @Ilya 3k+1 should be 2k+1.